# How can I add opencv library in my library module

Tags: android

- I am creating a small library which is based on opencv. I am able to add opencv as part of the main project but not in library module. Can any one help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Able to add in the main project but not in the library module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download Opencv library from the portal
2. Add opencv module in you project.
3. Generate aar file for the opencv module
4. Add the generated aar file as part of the library module.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).